# Unable to load Public Key with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Tags: openssl, redhat

Unable to load public key with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, but it works at OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017.

I know that base64 line length is limited to 76 characters by default in openssl ( and generated with 64 characters / line ), why it allows at the latest updates, but not for old one.

> unable to load Public Key 139727592335264:error:0906D064:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:812:

```
[tmp]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
[tmp]$ cat jon.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAySaRaKhe41cqMSP+ZmlfdbvbAvb/p6i7sQd/VlBHJHqMU7FlhYgLknQEZ22n/IipK1BYXdM6dwE/gQ/EaJxCdsrDpVEfA7fJPIuQUHLHiXLmmck5wnu+9Jmrxa3H68WpBYgaV0Kg6EZmU9IK1upyKc/P6ugve4ry0Es4KWbyke0KgqpkvzJ75b/EorKxdBWzRAhYmjiOBI8A37F2aABuNAlFTwnSuzbPVtDWz3jfWCzX7lp9q2NrXZDBzzYQdhH7erm1U7UXlF3B9Hyf4enZ6/qj4f2qLDyobwi3ah7eMOzAEGcd2kihfSwIlmChDbUwt7ya4xVq7jbBBYyh49qqGwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

[tmp]$ openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -text -out key_rsa_convert.pem < jon.pem
unable to load Public Key
139727592335264:error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:812:


[tmp]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
[amssys@APL14241APP001 tmp]$ cat jon.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAySaRaKhe41cqMSP+ZmlfdbvbAvb/p6i7sQd/VlBHJHqMU7FlhYgLknQEZ22n/IipK1BYXdM6dwE/gQ/EaJxCdsrDpVEfA7fJPIuQUHLHiXLmmck5wnu+9Jmrxa3H68WpBYgaV0Kg6EZmU9IK1upyKc/P6ugve4ry0Es4KWbyke0KgqpkvzJ75b/EorKxdBWzRAhYmjiOBI8A37F2aABuNAlFTwnSuzbPVtDWz3jfWCzX7lp9q2NrXZDBzzYQdhH7erm1U7UXlF3B9Hyf4enZ6/qj4f2qLDyobwi3ah7eMOzAEGcd2kihfSwIlmChDbUwt7ya4xVq7jbBBYyh49qqGwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

[amssys@APL14241APP001 tmp]$ openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -text -out key_rsa_convert.pem < jon.pem
writing RSA key
```